# Flags to Close don't send posts to the Vote to Close Review; is this intentional?

Tags: feature-request, review, flags

When you *vote* to close a post, the post is sent to the [review flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close) for 3kers to ponder on.

[image]

When you *flag* to close a post, the post is instead sent to [the 10k tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged).

[image]

To go from one place to the other and review posts with essentially the same kind of potential problems you have to click Review, then Tools, then Flags. Can we improve on this and also send flags to close to the review queues?

Comment: Note: Flags can be from anyone with 15 rep, while close vote can only be cast with 3k+ rep. I expect them to be treated differently. (A different close queue for close flags is probably OK. I don't think it is a good idea to mix everything up in one queue).

Comment: @nhahtdh ...so why escalate them to basically just the moderators' attention? The flags tab of the 10k tool is pretty hidden nowadays.

Comment: I think the visibility can be increased by giving it a separate queue. I just don't think mixing it together with normal close queue is a good idea.